# C# Video Converter library

Tags: c#, video, encoding

I am looking for a C# library(not commandline), commerical or free, that has the power similar to FFempeg. Video encoding is most important.

Any suggestions?

Best Regards,
Rune

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Mencoder GUI. It is no library (winforms application) but you can download sources and make anything you need: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mewig/files/ (you'll need mencoder.exe - www.mplayerhq.hu)

Comment: Sorry, dont have time for doing it myself. Must have something fully working. Commercial products are welcome.

Comment: @Rune - I think the best commercial suite is StreamCoders Media Suite (http://streamcoders.com/). You can find more information here: http://streamcoders.com/products/msnet.html . I think it is very good solution for you

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [FFLib](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/) - it is a .net wrapper around FFMpeg

Or you could roll your own - a good starting point is [here](http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/)

Comment: The FFLib is a Alpha version from 2008. Dont want to create one myself.

Answer (score 2):

[AVBlocks SDK](http://www.avblocks.com/) provides a .NET API that can be used from C# and VB.NET. AVBlocks supports most major audio and video codecs.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [NReco.VideoConverter](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx) - free all-in-one-DLL .NET FFMpeg wrapper. It executes ffmpeg as separate process (not linked with ffmpeg DLL) so all GPL codecs are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nuget package:

I haven't seen any project fullfilling my expectaction so i decided to make my own.
You can easily queue conversions and run it parallel, methods to convert media to different formats, send your own arguments to ffmpeg and parse output from ffmpeg + event listener with current progress.

`Install-Package Xabe.FFmpeg`

I'm trying to make easy to use, cross-platform FFmpeg wrapper.

You can find more information about this at [Xabe.FFmpeg](https://xabe.net/product/xabe_ffmpeg/)

More info here: [Xabe.FFmpeg Documentation](https://xabe.net/product/xabe_ffmpeg/#documentation)

Conversion is simple:

```
IConversionResult result = await Conversion.ToMp4(Resources.MkvWithAudio, output).Start();
```

If you want progress:

```
IConversion conversion = Conversion.ToMp4(Resources.MkvWithAudio, output);
conversion.OnProgress += (duration, length) => { currentProgress = duration; } 
await conversion.Start();
```

Comment: Just for known, Xabe.FFmpeg is for non-commercial use.

Comment: It's free for non-commercial use. You can still use it after buying it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try gstreamer here It has c# bindings

"gstreamer-sharp is a .NET/mono binding for Gstreamer
generated from gobject-introspection data using the bindinator"

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp